# What does `impl ... for` mean?

Tags: rust

I see the following pattern coming up a lot in Rust codebases, but I can't find an explanation why this is used.

For what end does one use the `impl ... for` construction?

Pseudocode:

```
impl Handler {
    pub fn method1() -> () {
    }
}
```

```
impl Dummy for Handler {
    pub fn method2() -> () {
    }
}
```

Comment: It's for implementing traits for types, check the [Rust book on traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`impl Struct ...` adds some methods to `Struct`. These methods aren't available to other types or traits.

`impl Trait for Struct ..` implements the trait `Trait` for the struct `Struct`. This results in the methods of the trait being available for `Struct`.

So, even though these two syntaxes look similar, they do 2 completely different things.
`impl Struct ...` adds new (not previously defined) methods to the type, while the other adds previously defined methods (from the trait) to the type.